# Convert array of items to key value [javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My array is something like this:

```
languages: ["Afrikaans","Albanian","Arabic","Azerbaijani", "Bengali"...]
```

I want to convert it so that it looks like:

```
languages: [{id:0,"Afrikaans"},{id:1,"Albanian"},{id:2,"Arabic"},{id:3,"Azerbaijani"}, {id:4,"Bengali"},...]
```

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid and will throw a syntax error

Comment: so, basically you'd like to convert an indexed collection into ... an indexed collection that't just more verbose and harder to crawl? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an object in each iteration step and then return this obj to build the result array.
I have added a key for your languages because otherwise it isn't valid syntax.

```js
let languages = ["Afrikaans","Albanian","Arabic","Azerbaijani", "Bengali"]
let res = languages.map((x, ind) => {
 let obj = {
 "id": ind,
 "lang": x
 }
 return obj;
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop does the trick here, and your final result is an array filled with incorrectly formatted objects so I took the liberty of adding the `language` property as you can see.

Let `listOfLanguagesArray` be your first array and `finalArray` be your result

```
var listOfLanguagesArray = ["Afrikaans","Albanian","Arabic","Azerbaijani", "Bengali"...];
var finalArray = [];
for (var j = 0; j < listOfLanguagesArray.length; j++) {
    finalArray.push({
        id: j,
        language: listOfLanguagesArray[j]
    });
}
```

It does seem that, however, what you're asking for is tedious and unnecessary work because you can traverse an array with more efficient methods than traversing an array of objects for the same information in the same order.